# MediaSource in iPhone iOS WKWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari, wkwebview

I'm using MediaSource sourcebuffer in an Ionic application:

```
this.mediaSource = new MediaSource();
this.mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', (_) => {
    this.sourceBuffer = this.mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mime);
});
this.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(chunk);
```

It's working on Android but not on iPhone iOS. My understanding is that Ionic uses WKWebView which doesn't seem to support MediaSource.

More precisely, according to https://caniuse.com/?search=mediasource, it seems to be working in iPad but not on iPhone.

Is there an alternative, an option or a hack to use MediaSource in iPhone iOS WKWebView?

Answer (score 0):

MediaSource is not supported on iOS for iPhone. It is only supported on iPadOS 13 or later.

CanIUse.com does state this in the notes if you look at the Safari for iOS column.

There is no way around this until Apple updates iOS to support MediaSource on iPhone.

Comment: What is the value of your answer??? You restate what I'm saying in the question and you are not aware of any solution...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. There absolutely is no solution. There are no hacks or workarounds. It is not supported on iOS for iPhone.

Comment: I found a solution with a different approach. You don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: That's great news. Would you mind sharing the workaround you found?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).